# How to send selected row attribute to spring controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have populated grid in JSP as follows

```
<c:forEach items="${leagueJoinList}" var="leagueList">
    <tr align="center" class="courseRow">
        <td>${leagueList.leagueName}</td>
        <!-- //finfd clicked index and set league id value from that-->
        <td>
            <form:hidden path="leagueId" value="${leagueList.leagueId}"/>
        </td>

        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"
                    onClick="joinLeague()">Join
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I am using a hidden field to assign currently selected row attribute to the path variable of the model attribute.
But instead of getting a single value in the controller, I am getting a comma separated list of all the values of that attribute in the list.
This is the form which I have to submit and the grid is included in side this form

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/searchLeagues"
           method="POST"
           modelAttribute="leagueObj"
           id="joinLeagueForm_">
```

and the button is also included in the same form but outside the table

```
<button id="primaryButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-link"
                        name="joinLeagues" value="joinLeagues">Join</button>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using single button for submitting data. here if you submit , that means you are sending total table list of data to server side , server side you will get list of table data because you are using single submit(join) button .

but, your requirement is to send particular row data , for that you need to maintain separate id for every row or better to use separate button for every row. then only you can send particular row data to server.

if you use separate id's for every row then better to use Jquery or Javascript for capturing data for passing object use ajax.

if it helps please promote.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach items="${leagueJoinList}" var="leagueList">
 <tr align="center" class="courseRow">
    <td>${leagueList.leagueName}</td>
    <td><a href="<c:url value="/searchLeagues/${leagueList.leagueId}"/>" class= "btn btn-primary"/>Join</td>              
 </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

try above code. This will create a button in each row with leagueId associated. Create a controller to map request with c:url tag's value.

Remove the form tag and button outside the table that you are using.

PS: I have never used attributes directly as ${leagueList.leagueId}. If this would not work try using ${leagueList.getLeagueId()}. Remember to have getter method in model class for leagueId and similar for other attributes also.